# Is it guaranteed by C++ standard that std::basic_string::npos + 1 == 0?

Tags: c++

I'm looking to eliminate special case in algorithm, and in order to do so I'd like to be sure that `std::string::npos + 1` is `0`.

This is true in all the implementations I have tested, and searching in the standard I have found the following:

```
namespace std {
  template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
    class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
  class basic_string {
    // ...
    typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;
    // ...
    static const size_type npos = -1;
    ...
  };
}
```

`allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type` is defined as an unsigned integer type.

So, I suppose, my question boils down to whether `(static_cast<T>(-1)) + 1` always gives `0` for unsigned integer type T?

Comment: What about `numeric_limits<T>::max`?

Comment: I guess that yes, but I am not sure.

Comment: In C++11 you could `static_assert (std::string::npos + 1 == 0, "bizarre string::npos")`

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm receiving npos from another algorithm, so I'd like to collapse a case of `t = std::string()` if `pos == npos` and `return s.substr(0, pos + 1)` otherwise.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's right. The question is whether this `static_assert` is needed at all: maybe it's of the same utility as `static_assert(2+2 == 4, "bizzare +")`?

Comment: Probably yes, but the compiler would optimize that to nothing, and it is a useful reminder to the human programmer who would work next on your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's a very good point. Thank you.

Comment: The C++11 standard states at 21.4.5 that `static const size_type npos = -1;`. It seems to me therefore that adding `1` to it will always yield `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, adding one to the largest value of an unsigned integer type is not guaranteed to give you zero.

If `size_type` is defined as `unsigned short`, and `int` is wider than `unsigned short`, the LHS of your addition will be converted to the RHS, and you rely on the addition being performed in the LHS's type.

Worse yet, but this is far less likely to actually happen, if `unsigned short` has *exactly* the same number of value bits as `int`, the addition would overflow and result in undefined behaviour.

What you can do, however, is add `1U`, and convert the result of the addition back to `T`. That should generate exactly the same code on common implementations, but would be guaranteed to be valid for all.

Comment: If `sizeof(std::string::size_type) >= sizeof(int)` the promotion would be to *unsigned* and the behavior is guaranteed. The third paragraph *Worse yet, but…* is incorrect.

Comment: That's a special case for sizes smaller than `int` tho.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas To be precise, if the maximum value of `std::string::size_type` is larger than the maximum value of `int`. Yes, in that case the addition would be guaranteed to evaluate to zero. As for the "Worse yet" part, what's incorrect about it? (Remember that the sign bit does not count as one of the value bits. I'm talking about an implementation where `USHORT_MAX == INT_MAX`, which as I noted is very unlikely, but perfectly valid.)