# C++ How to get substring after a character?

Tags: c++, string, substring

For example, if I have

```
string x = "dog:cat";
```

and I want to extract everything after the ":", and return cat. What would be the way to go about doing this?

Comment: See the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: This question could have been avoided with a bit of research.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's top of Google results now.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this:

```
x.substr(x.find(":") + 1);
```

Comment: This is amazing !! <3

Comment: This creates a copy, which may not be what you want. In C++17 you can use [`std::string_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view) to avoid copying.

Comment: As mentioned in some of the other answers, you should handle the edge case of `find` returning `npos`. It is not guaranteed that `npos + 1` equals 0 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402961/is-it-guaranteed-by-c-standard-that-stdbasic-stringnpos-1-0).

Comment: What if I had "cat:dog:parrot:horse" and I want to get just horse? (So the last one :)

Comment: @rcs How should I do exactly same thing in C programming?

Answer (score 15):

I know it will be super late but I am not able to comment accepted answer. If you are using only a single character in `find` function use `''` instead of `""`. 
As Clang-Tidy says `The character literal overload is more efficient.`

So
    `x.substr(x.find(':') + 1)`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer from [rcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236858/rcs) can be improved. Don't have rep so I can't comment on the answer.

```
std::string x = "dog:cat";
std::string substr;
auto npos = x.find(":");

if (npos != std::string::npos)
    substr = x.substr(npos + 1);

if (!substr.empty())
    ; // Found substring;
```

Not performing proper error checking trips up lots of programmers. The string has the sentinel the OP is interested but throws std::out_of_range if pos > size().

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0, size_type count = npos ) const;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string x = "dog:cat";

  //prints cat
  std::cout << x.substr(x.find(":") + 1) << '\n';
}
```

Here is an implementation wrapped in a function that will work on a delimiter of any length:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_right_of_delim(std::string const& str, std::string const& delim){
  return str.substr(str.find(delim) + delim.size());
}

int main(){

  //prints cat
  std::cout << get_right_of_delim("dog::cat","::") << '\n';

}
```

Comment: Thinking of delims of any length is simply smart, so a +1

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
string x = "dog:cat";
int i = x.find_first_of(":");
string cat = x.substr(i+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
  string x="dog:cat";
  int pos = x.find(":");
  string sub = x.substr (pos+1);
  cout << sub;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is get the position of ':' from your string, then retrieve everything after that position using substring.

`size_t pos = x.find(":");      // position of ":" in str`

`string str3 = str.substr (pos);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string process(std::string const& s)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = s.find(':');
    if (pos!= std::string::npos)
    {
        return s.substr(pos+1,s.length());
    }
    else
    {
        return s;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::string s = process("dog:cat");
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: I have executed this code it works ..http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**..

```
std::stringstream x("dog:cat");
std::string segment;
std::vector<std::string> seglist;

while(std::getline(x, segment, ':'))
{
   seglist.push_back(segment);
}
```